# Get Current Month

Tags: java, mysql

This is sample my database:

- status     date
- Q       2012-08-02.
- Q       2012-08-01.
- Q       2012-09-03.

Here if i run my application means i wish to display 2. This is do following information.
 - check the database **current month+status=Q** after display how many matched information is totally you are got.for example totally 2 means the output is displayed 2.

Already i done get the total count value for **current date+status=Q** information.it is successfully completed.
Here i have use this code:

```
public class RetailerWs {
public int data(){
int count=0;

//count++;

try{
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  Connection con = DriverManager
     .getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro","root","");

  PreparedStatement statement =  con
     .prepareStatement("select * from orders where status='Q' AND date=CURDATE()");
  ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

  while(result.next()) {
    // Do something with the row returned.
    count++; //if the first col is a count.
  }     
}
catch (Exception exc) {
  System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
}


return count;
 }
 }
```

the another class is:

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args){
    RetailerWs obj = new RetailerWs();
    System.out.println(obj.data());
 }

}
```

the above code for get the information for **current date + status=Q**.
please help me how is write the code for **current month + status=Q**....

Comment: You should put more efforts in writing with proper grammar and punctuation.

Comment: @SkyDan, English is not everyone's mother tongue, not mine at least. Give him some slack will you. At least he is making the effort with the coding.

Comment: @user1570318, Please change your nick to a proper name. Also don't use u or r, please spell it properly. Please don't tell me you are writing this from your mobile phone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
select * from orders where status='Q' AND MONTH(date) = MONTH(CURDATE())
```

See [THIS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) for more information on the date and time functions of MySQL.

For the week, try:

```
select * from orders where status='Q' AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE())
```

For the week in THIS year, try:

```
select * from orders where status='Q' AND WEEK(date) = WEEK(CURDATE()) AND YEAR(date) = YEAR(CURDATE())
```

To have it all in one check use:

```
select * from orders where status='Q' AND YEARWEEK(date) = YEARWEEK(CURDATE())
```

Comment: ya it is correct...i got my output..thanks yar..thank you so much for you for your help.but also i wish to need status='Q'+current week means how is write the query

Comment: @user1570318 See my edited answer. If you are pleased with the answer, please consider accepting it. However, I would highly recommend having a look at the link I provided.

Comment: thanks you so much...it is successfully worked.thank you so much

Comment: hi i have one prblem here.if i have data for previous year 2011 for the same month , that also would be shown..so how is to do for dis particular year for month

Comment: @user1570318 Did you even look at the link I posted? By now you should be able to solve upcoming questions on your own. I edited my answer one last time with the solution...

Comment: @user1570318 I didn't mean to be rude, but you should try to solve things like that on your own first.

Comment: yes your point of view is correct...i will improve my knowledge from your advice.thank you